# ios - Core Data updating records

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am currently looking through documentation and the web, but I am not seeing what I am looking for and I would just like to confirm if what I am looking for exists:-)

As I understand it - this line of code allows me to add a record to the SQLite database which I am showing in my app through Core Data:

```
NSManagedObject *newSoftware = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:
```

Now is there a line similar to that that allows me to update the record I am working on?

something like this?

```
NSManagedObject *newSoftware = [NSEntityDescription updateCurrentObjectForEntityForName:
```

Thank you very much for the feedback:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here my previous answer on it. It is quite detailed to understand what is going on.

[How to update existing object in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571786/how-to-update-existing-object-in-core-data/10572134#10572134)

Based on **fumoboy007** comment, you have to update your object trough KVC if you have not set up a subclass for your managed object. If you haven't already I suggest to create it. The code looks like more cleaner since you can acess a managed object through properties.

Here a link on it:

[organising-core-data-for-ios](http://blog.chrismiles.info/2011/06/organising-core-data-for-ios.html)

Comment: Hi, I still have one question sorry hope you don't mind:-)

Instead of @"title == %@", @"Some Title"]; like in the link you gave me I use @"name == %@", self.appNameTxtFld.text];

Now the problem is that all my info rows in the array get changed not just the one I select. How can I be more specific in my actions?

Comment: @JeffKranenburg Sorry, I cannot understand, maybe add an edit to your answer and explain it there. I will try to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the offer to help, I went back to the drawing board as I ended up with so much code it started to look like spaghetti jungle:-) I got it working now, not exactly in this way but I understand it now. I'll keep you in my list of go to people when I have a Core Data issue. You seem to know that part pretty well:-)

Answer (score 11):

To update a record, you simply update the `NSManagedObject`'s properties. If you're using CoreData, you should have `NSManagedObject`s for each of your "tables". Get a reference to an object after you've queried the database (using `NSFetchRequest`). Then you can update the record like this: `myObject.firstName = "John";`
When you're ready to update the object in your Sqlite database, just call your `NSManagedContext`'s `save` method. I suggest play with a CoreData sample app (like the default one generated by Xcode) to understand this better.

Comment: Note: `myObject.firstName = @"John";` only works if you created a NSManagedObject subclass. If you didn't do that, then you would need to do `[myObject setValue:@"John" forKey:@"firstName"]`.

Comment: I had this set up before I asked the question, but instead of updating a record it added it as a new one.