# How to overwrite Core Data attribute in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift

I'm trying to update an attribute in Core Data and then display it. However, when I tell the program to display it, it displays the original value.

Based off the code below, `username` is set to a String. I know 100% that `username` is saved into Core Data. However, when I try to update it, it saves to Core Data, but prints out the old value. How can I print out only the "newest" value?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class NameSettings: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var nameText: UITextField!

var userID: String!
var username: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)

    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    var res = results [0] as NSManagedObject

    userID = res.valueForKey("userID") as String
    username = res.valueForKey("username") as String

    println(username)

    nameText.text = username

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    //println(userID)

    var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userID) {
        (update1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            update1["username"] = self.nameText.text
            update1.saveEventually()

            var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)

            var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

            var updateUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

            updateUser.setValue(self.nameText.text, forKey: "username")

            context.save(nil)

            //println(self.nameText.text)

            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)


        }
    }

}

}
```

NOTE: All the `println`'s are just for debugging.

Comment: With `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` you're inserting a new value. Not overwriting the old.

Comment: Oh....I don't know the in's and out's of Core Data. Would you mind helping me out with fixing this issue? :)

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10572134/2274694

Comment: I don't know anything about Obj-C..... :/

Comment: Is there a way that I can delete the current value, and then "insert" the new value?

Comment: Which core data object are you trying to overwrite? "res" (i.e. the first object)?

Comment: I want to overrite "username". In my core data model, I have an entity named "Users" and an attribute named "username". This is what I want to change.

Comment: Yeah, but you can have multiple NSManagedObjects in your data model. From your viewDidLoad though, it looks like you're accessing the very first NSManagedObject object: `var res = results [0] as NSManagedObject`

Comment: Ok....so I guess I want to overwrite res. But isn't that going to screw up "UserID"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code stands now, you're not overwriting any `NSManagedObject`; you're inserting a new one, i.e. `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`.

Instead, what you can do is declare the `NSManagedObject` you want to save and the `NSManagedObjectContext` you want to save to as global variables; then simply set a new value for the `NSManagedObject`'s relevant key before saving to the `NSManagedObjectContext`, ex:

```
var userID: String!
var username: String!
var res : NSManagedObject!
var context : NSManagedObjectContext!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //...

    context = appDel.managedObjectContext! // <-- Use global var

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    res = results [0] as NSManagedObject // <-- Use global var

    //...
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    //println(userID)

    var query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userID) {
        (update1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            update1["username"] = self.nameText.text
            update1.saveEventually()

            res.setValue(self.nameText.text, forKey: "username")

            context.save(nil)

            //println(self.nameText.text)

            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works perfectly. Thanks for your time and help! At least now I understand where I was going wrong! :)